# Vagrant Homestead nginx provision error

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant

When I'm running vagrant provisioning I get this error. Can anyone help me?

I'm using antoniofrignani/laravel-homestead-settler-32 box in vagrant and it was working nice until yesterday.

[image: error image]

Comment: have you tried to destroy and create the machine? (i.e. ```vagrant destroy```) **NOTE** This will erase any data that was on the machine. Or alternatively start a new machine somewhere else from scratch

Comment: Yes I have but it doesn´t work. I solved it using the ubuntu/trusty32 box in Vagrantfile.

Comment: is there anything specific you need from the ```laravel-homestead-settler-32``` box? or does ```trusty32``` is good enough?